# Descargar archivo con un nombre especifico aspx

Tags: javascript, html5, aspx

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me descarga un archivo pdf

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "prueba"); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(FilePDF, 0, FilePDF.Length);
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Sin embargo al momento que hace la descarga me descarga el archivo pdf con el siguiente nombre raro: 221b11ec-7b46-4ba6-9209-78b411c57006.pdf. Lo que realmente yo quiero es descargar el archivo pero con el nombre que le estoy poniendo en el AddHeader el cual es "prueba" pero no lo consigo. Siempre se me descarga con otro nombre. Alguien sabe como podria hacerlo. De antemano gracias.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que sea eso, pero la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition pone en los ejemplos el nombre del fichero entre " (es decir `"attachment; filename=\"prueba\""`). No recuerdo que fuera necesario cuando lo he usado yo, pero puedes probarlo. Intenta también ponerle una extensión adecuada (".pdf") por si acaso.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando implementas outputStream puedes implmentar [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream?view=netframework-4.8)

```
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Otra opcion y la que veo que has intentado aplicar es esta [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694129/12684857)

```
var cd = new ContentDisposition 
{
    FileName = "file.mp3"
};
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

Por ultimo esto tambien te puede funcionar [Link](https://forums.asp.net/t/977806.aspx?Response%20OutputStream%20and%20file%20name)

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=YourFileName.gif");
```